# Select options dropdown not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select list of options that change the content according to the selection. It works fine in MS Edge, IE, and on FireFox except in Chrome. Maybe I am missing something, below are all my code:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab option {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab option:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab option.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <select class="tab">
    <option value="london" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</option>
    <option value="paris" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</option>
  </select>

  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't attach `click` events directly to `<option>`s. The way you get the selected option is by listening for the `change` event on the `<select>`.

After the change, `this` in your `openCity` function, refers to the `<select>`. I'm getting the selected text like this:

```js
  this.options[this.selectedIndex].text // Paris, London, etc.
```

These values match up with the `id`s of your `.tabcontent` `<div>s`. Then we show the content.

```js
  document.getElementById(
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
  ).style.display = "block";
```

```js
document.querySelector('.tab').addEventListener('change', openCity);

function openCity(evt) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
  ).style.display = "block";

  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab option {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab option:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab option.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="tab">
  <option value="london" class="tablinks">London</option>
  <option value="paris" class="tablinks">Paris</option>
</select>


<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edcaztxf/1/)

Comment: Now I am trying to make the tab with London tab open by default document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RochaCarter07 I've added the change to the bottom of the new [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edcaztxf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the onClick Event within option Elements. Use the onChange event of the select instead. Try to take selected value using an event. Try this code. This will work fine in chrome also.

```
<body>
<select class="tab" onchange="openCity(event)">
    <option value="london" class="tablinks">London</option>
    <option value="paris" class="tablinks">Paris</option>
</select>

<div id="london" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
</body>

function openCity(evt) {
        var cityName = evt.target.value;
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
   }
```